# monit and run script

Tags: shell-script, shell, monitoring, monit

I want monitor `MariaDB` with `monit tools`. 
my `monit script` is :

```
check process mariadb_pid with pidfile /var/lib/mysql/db1.pid
check program telnet with path "/root/telnet.sh"
   if status eq 99 then exec "/usr/bin/systemctl restart mariadb.service"
```

and `telnet script` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /root/ips | \
while read host port; do
  result=$(bash -c 'exec 3<> /dev/tcp/'$host'/'$port';echo $?' 2>/dev/null)
  echo $result
 if [ "$result" != "0" ]; then
        exit 99
 fi
done
```

`ips` file is:

 `192.168.10.10 3306
 192.168.10.20 3306`

Now, it is expected if mariadb ip1 and ip2 in ips file is down, then execute

`if status eq 99 then exec "/usr/bin/systemctl restart mariadb.service"`

But not running. please look monit log.

```
[EST Mar  5 00:34:19] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:34:24] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:34:29] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:34:34] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:34:39] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:34:44] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:34:49] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:34:54] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:34:59] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:04] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:09] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:14] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:19] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:24] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:29] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:34] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:39] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:44] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:49] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:35:54] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:00] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:05] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:10] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:15] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:20] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:25] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:30] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:35] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:40] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:45] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:50] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1    
[EST Mar  5 00:36:55] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1
```

also, when restart monit, This line runs for the first time.

```
[EST Mar  5 00:39:05] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:10] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:15] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:20] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:25] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:26] info     : Reinitializing monit daemon                       
[EST Mar  5 00:39:26] info     : Reinitializing Monit -- control file '/etc/monitrc
[EST Mar  5 00:39:26] info     : 'db1' Monit reloaded                              
[EST Mar  5 00:39:31] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:31] info     : 'telnet' exec: '/usr/bin/systemctl restart mariadb.service'                                                                              
[EST Mar  5 00:39:36] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:41] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:46] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:51] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:39:56] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1                  
[EST Mar  5 00:40:01] error    : 'telnet' status failed (99) -- 1
```

Does anyone have any experience in this field?